# Can't Shorten NSString Length

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to make this program so that the only time that there is a decimal is when the decimal is `.5`. I have been trying to use `[string substringToIndex:[string length] - 2]` but it does nothing. Is is because it cannot append the float?

```
float inchesInField = [sizeField.text floatValue];
float shoeSize = inchesInField * 3 - 22;
NSMutableString *appendedShoeSize = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                                            initWithFormat:@"%.1f", shoeSize];

if ([appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".3"] || [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".5"] ||
    [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".4"] || [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".6"])
{
    [appendedShoeSize substringToIndex:[appendedShoeSize length] - 2];
    [appendedShoeSize appendString:@" ½"];
} 

if ([appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".0"] || [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".1"] ||
    [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".2"])
{
    [appendedShoeSize substringToIndex:[appendedShoeSize length] - 2];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because substringToIndex: method of NSString returns the new string, it doesn't modify the original string. appendString: is fine, but substringToIndex: is a method of NSString so it will not edit the original string.

This should do it:

```
float inchesInField = [sizeField.text floatValue];
float shoeSize = inchesInField * 3 - 22;
NSMutableString *appendedShoeSize = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.1f", shoeSize];

if ([appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".3"] || [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".5"] || [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".4"] || [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".6"]) {

    appendedShoeSize = [[appendedShoeSize substringToIndex:[appendedShoeSize length] - 2] mutableCopy];
    [appendedShoeSize appendString:@" ½"];
} 

if ([appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".0"] || [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".1"] || [appendedShoeSize hasSuffix:@".2"]) {

    appendedShoeSize = [[appendedShoeSize substringToIndex:[appendedShoeSize length] - 2] mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: Of course, one can use `deleteCharactersInRange` on an NSMutableString to truncate it in place.

Comment: That would be a more consistent use of NSMutableString in this case

Comment: When I tried this I got a warning: "incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableString *__strong' from 'NSString *'

Comment: i didn't try out the code, I just illustrated that the result of substringToIndex: should be assigned back to appendedShowSize. Sorry. The warning would be that substringToIndex: returns an NSString, and we're trying to assign it back to an NSMutableString... I'll update the above by sending mutableCopy message creating an NSMutableString from the NSString

Comment: @AppleGuy -- the value returned from `substringToIndex` will be an NSString, not an NSMutableString (since the implementation of that method is with NSString, and NSMutableString does not override it).

Comment: sure so we can use mutableCopy to create n NSMutableString from this result, as the updated sample code reflects.

Comment: if this was the solution could you mark is as correct please ? thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you call  substringToIndex:, it won't modify the existing string. It returns a result. You have to use something like : 
    NSString * result = [appendedShoeSize substringToIndex:[appendedShoeSize length] - 2];

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel pointed out `substringToIndex:` returns a new string.

You should use `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`, for example:

```
NSRange range; range.location = [appendedShoeSize length] - 2; range.length = 2;
[appendedShoeSize replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@" ½"]
```

More reference about NSMutableString methods can be found at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but an alternative, all those `hasSuffix:`'s just grated a bit. I think this does what you want:

```
float intpart;
float fracpart = modff(shoeSize, &intpart);
NSMutableString *appendedShoeSize;

int size = (int)intpart;
if (fracpart >= 0.3 && fracpart <= 0.6)
    appendedShoeSize = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d½", size];
else
{   if (fracpart > 0.6) size += 1;
    appendedShoeSize = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", size];
}
```

`modff` splits a float into its fractional (return value) and integer (via reference argument) parts. This code fragment doesn't require a mutable string, but I left that in as you might be doing other things with it later. The fragment also bumps .7 -> .9 to the next size.